# Gradle does not download most recent Maven package modification

Tags: java, maven, gradle, libgdx

I am trying to download my maven repository as a dependency with Gradle (and LibGdx) in Eclipse into another project which requires the sources.jar to be included (because of GWT), but I am running into a problem. I did not realize that snapshot uploads do not also upload a sources and javadoc jar by default so I decided to add those plugins to my pom.xml and reupload the repository. You can see the directory on Sonatype [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/strongjoshua/libgdx-inGameConsole/0.3.0-SNAPSHOT/). ***EDIT*** Note that I tried deleting the entire directory and reuploading a new version, but my local Gradle cache still has the first upload's details stored and refuses to update them.

*I am refreshing the Gradle Dependencies under `Grade->Refresh All`, but this is where I get the error resulting from Gradle not downloading the newest version of the maven repo.*

I assumed that maven would just overwrite the older uploads, but as I see now, it does not. But I also thought that Gradle would download the newest modification by default, which, apparently it does not, which I know because

a) I checked the file that Gradle downloaded, and it is the oldest modification.
b) The oldest jar was not uploaded with a sources.jar attached, which is the whole reason I reuploaded, so I am still getting the missing sources.jar error.

Is this a *feature* and I will have to add my own arbitrary denominators to my snapshots when I want to update them (like nightlies), is this a bug in Gradle, or did I do something wrong in my Gradle configurations?

This is my build.gradle from the LibGdx game:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-beta-01'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'Test'
        gdxVersion = '1.5.2'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-beta-01'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
        ashleyVersion = '1.3.1'
        aiVersion = '1.4.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion:sources"
        compile "com.strongjoshua:libgdx-inGameConsole:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT:sources"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
        compile "com.strongjoshua:libgdx-inGameConsole:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

This is the specific Gradle error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':html:compile'.
> Artifact 'libgdx-inGameConsole-sources.jar (com.strongjoshua:libgdx-inGameConsole:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT)' not found.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/strongjoshua/libgdx-inGameConsole/0.3.0-SNAPSHOT/libgdx-inGameConsole-0.3.0-20150411.180117-1-sources.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.873 secs
[sts] Build failed
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:71)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.TaskUtil.execute(TaskUtil.java:117)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.TaskUtil.execute(TaskUtil.java:55)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.TaskUtil.bulkRunTasks(TaskUtil.java:187)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.wizards.GradleImportOperation.doBeforeTasks(GradleImportOperation.java:280)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.wizards.GradleImportOperation.perform(GradleImportOperation.java:182)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.actions.ReimportOperation.perform(ReimportOperation.java:59)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.actions.RefreshAllActionCore$1$1.doit(RefreshAllActionCore.java:89)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.actions.Continuable.doit(Continuable.java:44)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable$1.run(GradleRunnable.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':html:compile'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':html:compile'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.access$000(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:446)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:205)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:182)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection$1.resolve(CompositeFileCollection.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileCollection.java:143)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileTree.java:30)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getFiles(CompositeFileCollection.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.<init>(TaskUpToDateState.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:126)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Artifact 'libgdx-inGameConsole-sources.jar (com.strongjoshua:libgdx-inGameConsole:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT)' not found.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/strongjoshua/libgdx-inGameConsole/0.3.0-SNAPSHOT/libgdx-inGameConsole-0.3.0-20150411.180117-1-sources.jar
    at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$LocateInCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactFromCache(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:253)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$LocateInCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:237)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveArtifact(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.projectmodule.ProjectArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(ProjectArtifactResolver.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ContextualArtifactResolver$3.execute(ContextualArtifactResolver.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ContextualArtifactResolver$3.execute(ContextualArtifactResolver.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ContextualArtifactResolver$4.run(ContextualArtifactResolver.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:187)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ContextualArtifactResolver.executeInContext(ContextualArtifactResolver.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ContextualArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(ContextualArtifactResolver.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.oldresult.DefaultResolvedConfigurationBuilder$LazyArtifactSource.create(DefaultResolvedConfigurationBuilder.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.oldresult.DefaultResolvedConfigurationBuilder$LazyArtifactSource.create(DefaultResolvedConfigurationBuilder.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultResolvedArtifact.getFile(DefaultResolvedArtifact.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$2.run(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:112)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:187)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.getFilesStrict(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:188)
    ... 70 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. Turns out all is fixed if I change the my build.gradle file to reference an older version of the repository, download it (refresh dependencies) and then switch back to the new one. Welp...

Answer (score 2):

By default Gradle uses dependencies caches and will not check for new versions in every invocation of the build:

> Gradle contains a highly sophisticated dependency caching mechanism,
>   which seeks to minimise the number of remote requests made in
>   dependency resolution, while striving to guarantee that the results of
>   dependency resolution are correct and reproducible.

However, you can force the dependency refresh by using the `--refresh-dependencies` option from the command line:

> At times, the Gradle Dependency Cache can be out of sync with the
>   actual state of the configured repositories. Perhaps a repository was
>   initially misconfigured, or perhaps a “non-changing” module was
>   published incorrectly. To refresh all dependencies in the dependency
>   cache, use the --refresh-dependencies option on the command line.

You can read more about gradle dependencies cache in gradle documentation [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:dependency_cache).

Comment: I had tried deleting the folder containing the old jars in my local gradle cache but it only redownloaded the same ones I deleted. Is this different?

Comment: According to the documentation the Gradle dependency cache consists of 2 key types of storage: (1) the file-based store of downloaded artifacts which I guess is what you deleted and (2) a binary store of resolved module meta-data, including the results of resolving dynamic versions, module descriptors, and artifacts. If you did not delete the second storage then this might make a difference.

Comment: Alright, I can understand that, but then how do nightlies work? They have the same name, but different modification dates... Also, how do I execute that command if I only have Gradle as a plugin in Eclipse?

Comment: Regarding the nightlies then by default gradle cache is for 24 hours, but it can be further controlled by fine tuning it using resolutionStrategy (see section 51.9.3). Regarding eclipse then i'm right click the project, in the context menu select Gradle and finally choose "Refresh Dependencies"

Comment: Ah, I guess I didn't clarify that. Please check my update (the italicized text under the first paragraph).